# Ruby on Rails Tutorial(3.2) Chapter 7 Exercises Listing 7.32 rspec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After adding the rspec test provided in **Listing 7.32** rspec is having trouble returning a User object using the **find_by_email** method. The rspec test fails with a message "***NoMethodError: undefined method name for nil:NilClass***" which is essentially telling me it could not find the user and hence no User object was returned. Any insights to why this specific finder method is failing while others work would be helpful.

I added a single user using the info provided at the start of the Chapter 7 Examples section which specifies "**Rails Tutorial**" for the name and "**example@railstutorial.org**" for the email. I also changed the rspec *have_selector* method to match the user's *name* in the HTML *h1* tag instead of the HTML *title* tag. The rspec tests pass if I use other finder methods such as **User.first** or **User.find(1)** but fails when I use **User.find_by_email("example@railstutorial.org")**. If I open a rails console(development mode) I can return the correct user using the find_by_email method. If I open a rails console(test mode) no users are in the database. I ran `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` and re-ran it but the rspec test still failed. I can print out the correct results when changing the spec to use *User.first* and printing out the *name* and *email* with `pp user.name, user.email` but rspec gets lost when attempting to use **User.find_by_email("example@railstutorial.org")**.

## Environment

ruby 1.9, rails 3.2.3, Ubuntu 10.04

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass','2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby','3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails','2.9.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara','1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails','1.4.0'
end

#Javascript runtime for Linux
gem 'therubyracer' 

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  before_save { self.email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum:20}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, 
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, length: {minimum:6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

### user_pages rspec(snippet)

```
describe "signup" do
  before { visit signup_path }
  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }
  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
    describe "after submission" do
      before { click_button submit }
      it { should have_selector('title',text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_content('error') } 
    end
  end
  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end
    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
    describe "after saving the user" do
      before { click_button submit }
      let(:user) { User.find_by_email("example@railstutorial.org") }
      it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) #error with name on NilClass!
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome')}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill your form with the email=`user@example.com` but try to find the user in you db with email=`example@railstutorial.org`. Make them to be the same.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I'm not that familiar with rspec/capybara so I guess I am not seeing the connection between `fill_in ...` and `let(:user){...}`. I was thinking _fill_in_ related to the _signup page_ form field values and had no connection to returning a User object. Therefore I was thinking the response from `before{click_button submit}` would be the HTML for the _profile page_ and that it wouldn't even have an form fields to fill in.

Comment: You're absolutely right! *fill_in* related to the *signup*. When you call `click_button submit` your user with email `user@example.com` is being added to your test DB. The result -- new user's page with info about his user. Then `User.find_by_email` is searching for this user in your DB and assigns it to the `user` variable. Of course your filled email and the email of the user in your DB are the same: `user@example.com`. But you try to get the user with non-existing email, which obviously returns `nil`. So, your `user`=nil. Trying to call `user.name` in this case is the same as `nil.name`.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain. I must have a StackOverflow moron badge with my name on it somewhere for two dumb questions in a row. I made the mistake of thinking `User.find_by_email` was pulling from the _development_ DB instead of the _test_ DB. Time for me to find a good rspec book/reference.